# problem loading model/texture of item forge 1.12.2 (intellij idea)

Tags: minecraft-forge

I have tried to change the name of the item and it doesn't work

o ya my lang file doesn't work too

error:

> Exception loading model for variant rpc:ingot_titinium#inventroy for item "rpc:ingot_titinium", normal location exception

https://pastebin.com/WnNGPAGZ

---

```
public void registerModel(Item item, int metadata)
{
    ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, metadata, new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName(), "inventory"));
}
```

edit:
[folder structure and ref code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEq9U.png)

Comment: Typo in `inventroy`, which should be `inventory` (`or` instead of `ro`). Also, make sure your model file name matches and exists.

Comment: thanks for addersing the topo but it didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using intellij idea, add at the bottom of your build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets { main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir } }
```